# A framework to create web forms with little code and can send form data to a database, email address, or other apis

Tags: html, .net, sql, forms, rest

Does anyone know of a framework to create web forms that requires little code and can send form data to a database, email address, or other api such as Microsoft CRM? I am looking for a framework where I can define the form and fields in a database which then creates the form and web endpoint automatically.  Ideally I would like the form data to be stored in a normalized database.  A .net solution would be the best.

Comment: Maybe look at Microsoft LightSwitch or InfoPath...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for an off-the-shelf solution, of which there are many.  @David indicated in his comment that [Microsoft LightSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff796201.aspx) and [InfoPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_InfoPath) are viable options, to which I'd agree.  These offer the path of least resistance -- minimal hassle for setup, and forms can more or less be created without any coding required by the user.

If you're feeling adventurous and want to use a more capable framework, [Microsoft ASP.NET Webforms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms) is another technology that does exactly what you want really, really well.  It is considerably more dynamic/open/complex than Lightswitch/Infopath, but on the whole is an excellent option for someone that just needs to get editable forms/grids up and running in the shortest amount of time possible.

ASP.NET's drag and drop components are easy to use and configure -- you can literally wire up forms/grids to a database without having to code anything at all.  Another great thing about using Webforms is that you get the support of the entire .NET framework, which as hundreds(?) of components that you can take advantage of (grids, widgets, charts, etc. etc.).

Comment: I have done a quite a bit of programming in asp.net.  I was wondering if there was something already built to do what I am asking.  I will look into LightSwitch and InfoPath.

Answer (score 0):

.NET itself is a framework  PHP has lot of options in way that you are searching :)